# How to backup a remote Sybase database to a local file?

Tags: sap-ase, database-backups

I am connected remotely to a Sybase server that is on a UNIX machine. I am connected via isql GUI on a windows client. I do not have access to the UNIX server's interfaces file so I don't think I can set up my machine as a remote backup server.  Can I use the following command to get a backup on my Windows machine?

dump database mydb to "C:\mydb.dmp"

Also what is the performance penalty? The database is about 9GB.
I suppose I should run this in the off hours if possible?

Comment: That won't work.  Your best bet is probably to use the BCP utility, to export the data from each table.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I also wasn't just going to just try it in case I filled up the hard drive of the server. I already have a bcp script but was hoping to improve the process. I would accept this as an answer if you put it as one. Unless you think I can alter the interfaces file via isql or connect to the remote server's control center to change the interfaces file?

Comment: Thanks.  As far as editing the interfaces file, you have to have access to the filesystem of the system it's installed on.  I haven't used SCC, but I do not believe it would offer that functionality either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work. Your best bet is probably to use the **bcp** utility, to export the data from each table.

Answer (score 1):

Your windows machine should also:

1) have Sybase ASE AND Backup Service installed

2) define on both interfaces and sql.ini files in both instances.

Your command will then be:

`dump database mydb to "C:\mydb.dmp"` at wintel_bs

for more info: 
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31644.1600/doc/html/san1371158725683.html